# ConnectionString" setting

Tags: sql, instance

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 
>   25 - Connection string is not valid) Check Web.config file
>   "ConnectionString" setting.

connection string

```
<add key="ConnectionString" value="server=(local)\MSSQLSERVER;database=bugtracker;user id=sa;password=sa123!@#;Trusted_Connection=no"/>
```

Comment: In debug mode, are you able to output the connection string that's being retrieved? It will allow you to narrow down whether the problem is with the connection string or when retrieving the setting.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your connection string that you have declared in web.config file... show me your web.config file where you have declared your connection string.
Check your connection string properly

Comment: <add key="ConnectionString" value="server=(local)\MSSQLSERVER;database=bugtracker;user id=sa;password=sa123!@#;Trusted_Connection=no"/>

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer. Hold off on trying to answer until you actually have enough information to answer the question.